# While loop not breaking

Tags: python, while-loop

Below is a piece of code from Python which has been bothering me for a while.

```
var=0
while (var <1 or var>100):
    var=raw_input('Enter the block number ')
    if (var >=1 and var<=100):
        print '\nBlock Number : ',var 
    else:
        print 'ERROR!!! Enter again.'
```

The problem is that the while loop iterates continuously without breaking. Can anyone help me how to break the loop.

Is there any way to implement a *do..while* in Python?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `raw_input` returns a string.  You're comparing a string with an integer which you can do in python 2.x (In python 3, this sort of comparison raises a `TypeError`), but the result is apparently always `False`.  To make this work you probably want something like `var=int(raw_input('Enter the block number'))`

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> objects of different types always compare unequal, and are ordered consistently but arbitrarily.

Comment: `int`s are always less than `str`s

Comment: @ColinDunklau -- Is that actually true?  Or is that a CPython implementation detail?  The only thing that actually matters is that the objects are ordered consistently.

Comment: @mgilson good point, I believe it depends on the implementation. IIRC, it's only like that in python 2.x, as well.

Comment: @ColinDunklau -- Good point about only in python2.x.  I've updated my answer saying it's illegal in python 3 (and raises a `TypeError`)

Answer (score 4):

You're needlessly checking var twice, and you're trying to compare int and str (because raw_input returns a string), which doesn't work right. Try this:

```
var=0
while True:
    var=int(raw_input('Enter the block number '))
    if (var >=1 and var<=100):
        print '\nBlock Number : ',var 
        break
    else:
        print 'ERROR!!! Enter again.'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your string to int.

```
var=0
while (var <1 or var>100):
    # I changed here
    var=int(raw_input('Enter the block number '))
    if (var >=1 and var<=100):
        print '\nBlock Number : ',var 
    else:
        print 'ERROR!!! Enter again.'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running into an issue that strings (as returned by `raw_input`) are always greater than integers:

```
>>> "25" > 100
True
```

You need to convert your input to an integer first:

```
var = int(raw_input("Enter the block number "))
```

Of course, you'll want to be resilient in the face of bad input, so you'll probably want to wrap the whole thing in a `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

hello you need to enter "break" and also var should be an integer, see below

```
while True:
var=int(raw_input('Enter the block number '))
if (var >=1 and var<=100):
    print '\nBlock Number : ',var
    break
else:
    print 'ERROR!!! Enter again.'
    continue
```

hope this helps